# build a sparse matrix with a defined size by usings 3 matrices - R

Tags: r, matrix

I need to define a sparse matix with size with size `nrow(X)` which is made of these three matrices(II,JK,JH). thier size is equal to `3164*1`.
So far I got to the following command which is not correct.

```
Gradient <- sparseMatrix(II,JK,JH, dims=c(nrow(X),nrow(X)))
```

II has value from 3 to 82 (it has repeatation, for example 10 times value 3 and 14 times value 4).JK is also the same as II, but in II the values were sorted while in JK they do ot have and finally the JH which is -1 and 1.

Also the size of sparse matrix should be 83*83.

Any help would be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Please add minimal examples of II, JK, JH and X and your desired output. Please also add how your code output is incorrect. Without these we cannot help.

Comment: This will be easy to answer, but without data an answer requires a lot of guesswork. Which of the three vectors `II` `JK` `JH` contains the matrix elements? Which one contains the row index, and which one the column index? If you include a small reproducible example with a,  say, 5x6 matrix, you could have an answer within a few minutes.

Comment: @RHertel, I edited my question with the required information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that *might* help. The information in the post is not sufficient for being certain, but it is specific enough to assume that either 
this type of matrix or the transpose are the desired result.

First we create some mock data

```
set.seed(42) # for reproducibility of the example
II <- as.matrix(sample(7,replace=TRUE))
JK <- as.matrix(sample(7,replace=TRUE))
JH <- sample(c(1,-1),length(II),replace=TRUE)
```

*Note:*  The `as.matrix()` commands above are unnecessary, but the OP stated that 
the vectors `II`, `JK`, `JH` are stored as matrices, so I included them to obtain the same data class.

It doesn't make any difference whether those are one-dimensional matrices or 
non-dimensional vectors.

With this type of data, a sparse matrix can be generated as follows:

```
library(Matrix)
spMatrix(max(II), max(JK), i = II, j = JK, x = JH)
```

The result is the following sparse (7x7) matrix:

```
7 x 7 sparse Matrix of class "dgTMatrix"

[1,] .  . . .  . .  .
[2,] .  . . .  . .  .
[3,] .  . . . -1 .  .
[4,] .  . . .  . . -1
[5,] .  . . .  . 1  .
[6,] . -1 . 1  . .  .
[7,] 1  . . . -1 .  .
```

**Data used in this example:**

```
Row indices:
II <-  as.matrix(c(7, 7, 3, 6, 5, 4, 6))
Column indices:
JK <- as.matrix(c(1, 5, 5, 4, 6, 7, 2))
Matrix elements:
JH <- c(1, -1, -1,  1,  1, -1, -1)
```